# ExpressionTree. Using Lambda Expressions in Binary Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Is there any way to use lambdas in binary expressions (like Add, Subtract, etc) as arguments.

```
        Expression<Func<double>> foo = () => 5.5;
        Expression<Func<double>> bar = () => 10.5;
        Expression<Func<double>> res = Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(Expression.Add(bar, foo));
        Console.WriteLine(res.Compile()());
```

This throws `System.InvalidOperationException`: The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Func`1[System.Double]' and 'System.Func`1[System.Double]'.

I'm aware of `ConstantExpression`. I just want to call lambdas and use the result in arithmetic calculations. Is this even achievable? I'm clearly missing some of the fundamentals on how Expression Trees are implemented.

**EDIT**: I found out that similar thing can be achieved by using `MethodCallExpression` in arguments instead of `Expression<Func<double>>`. But the question remains relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the Add line to following

```
var res = Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(Expression.Add(bar.Body, foo.Body));
```

it will work.

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot!